# Least triangular convex polygon

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, polygons, extremal-combinatorics

(This question is based on a [question posed](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/itscmd/how_triangular_is_a_square/g5gzz7p/) in a [math riddle post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/itscmd/how_triangular_is_a_square/).)

Let $P$ be a convex polygon. Let the *non-triangularity* of $P$ be the minimum area of the symmetric difference (shown with infix operator $\oplus$) over all triangles and $P$, normalized to the volume of $P$: $$
  \inf_{T \subset \mathbb{R}^2,\text{ a triangle}} \left\{ \frac{\operatorname{area}(P \oplus T)}{\operatorname{area}(P)} \right\}
$$
In the picture below, the polygon $P$ is a rectangle, and we're trying to choose a triangle $T$ such that the area in orange is minimized.

[image: symmetric difference of a rectangle and a triangle]

Triangles have a non-triangularity of $0$, by "approximating" the triangle by itself. It's easy to construct an $n$-gon with very small non-triangularity: just make all but three of the sides arbitrarily small.

Also, all polygons $P$ have a triangularity less than $1$, just take a triangle $T$ in the interior, so that $\operatorname{area}(P \oplus T) = \operatorname{area}(P) - \operatorname{area}(T) < \operatorname{area}(P)$.

#### Question

What is the most non-triangular convex polygon? (Or, in the limit, the most non-triangular [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set)?)

Or if this question is too hard, what are some non-trivial bounds on how non-triangular a convex polygon can be? (Perhaps constructive lower bounds would be useful to see, for example, computing the non-triangularity of the square or the circle.)

If this question is too easy, what is the most non-triangular $n$-gon for each $n$?

Comment: Unless you **normalize** your measure in a way or another, for example by dividing area($P \oplus T$) by area($P$) (area of the polygonal shape), your issue is ill-defined (one can take arbitrarily large polygons). An additional interest of this kind of normalization is that a quotient of areas is invariant by affine transformations such as stretching.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen it. Nevertheless, I think it would be slightly more practical to have area($P \oplus T$)/area($P$) instead of making the initial assumption of normalization. Imagine for example that you have to consider a sequence of polygons... formula area($P_n \oplus T$)/area($P_n$) is usable at once...

Comment: In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863590/maximum-area-of-triangle-inside-a-convex-polygon/1863662#1863662) it is shown that every convex shape of area 1 has an inscribed triangle of area at least 3sqrt(3)/4pi ~ 0.413. So the non-triangularity of any shape is at most ~0.617. It may well be that the circle is the optimal shape (though its nontriangularity is not ~0.617).

Comment: @Lopsy Good catch!