# Polygon of maximum area contained in compact, convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, polygons

> Let $H$ be a compact, convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^2.$ For a given $m\ge 3,$ let $P_m$ be a polygon of maximum area which contained in $H$ and has atmost $m$ sides. Then $$\dfrac{Area(P_m)}{Area(H)}\ge\dfrac{m}{2\pi}\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{m}\right)$$ and equality holds if and only if $H$ is an ellipse.

I found this result fom [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=XZ7iBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=circular+symmetrization+of+an+ellipse&source=bl&ots=ZTE_4ZzqII&sig=gB6G7yuHoBp00eOdNdVsq9Kptvs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYz73106DWAhVDhlQKHbjmAfcQ6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=circular%20symmetrization%20of%20an%20ellipse&f=false) and has no clue to prove this. Any idea or a (easy) reference to attempt this problem?

Comment: Did you consider finding the proposition in the reference that the author suggested (Sas, or Dowker)?

Comment: I tried to find, but couldn't. DO you know a place to find these?

Comment: see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1871422/59379) to a related question. It attempt to illustrate an elegant analytic approach by E.Sas (1939).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think even a bound $\ge \epsilon_m$ has some value. I will provide an $\epsilon_3$.

Consider $H$ compact convex body. Take $\Delta A_1 A_2 A_3$ of largest area. The points $A_i$ are on the boundary. Because we cannot enlarge the area by moving $A_1$, there exists a supporting line to $H$ through $A_1$ that is parallel to $A_2 A_3$. Similarly for the other vertices. Thus we can inscribe $H$ in a larger triangle $\Delta A_1'A_2'A_3'$ for which the $A_i$'s are the midpoints. Therefore $\operatorname{Area}\Delta A_1 A_2 A_3 \ge \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Area}H$.

Notice that if $H$ were the ellipse tangent to the sides of the larger triangle at the midpoints $A_i$'s then we would have the exact bound stated ( the figure would be affinely equivalent to a circle inscribed in a equilateral triangle).

Comment: I would like to ask a question for more clarification. Why there should be a supporting line to $H$ through $A_1$ that is parallel to $A_2A_3$?

Comment: at any point , there is a cone of supporting lines. if that cone does not contain a line parallel to A2A3 then you can increase a bit the area by going up on that lin inside the region